# PMA: Login cookie validity -- difference between manual and in-file setting

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have changed phpMyAdmin's login cookie validity manually (via `Settings > Features > General > Login cookie validity`) to `36000`. Now, I want to change it to even bigger value, but using configuration variable (`$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']` in `config.inc.php`). It seeem, that I can't.

I have added `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 259200;` to `config.inc.php` of phpMyAdmin and `session.gc_maxlifetime = 259200` to `php.ini`. I have restarted Apache, MySQL and browser. Clearead its cache and re-logged in to phpMyAdmin. I see no difference -- value is still `36000`.

To make things even more complicated, I see, that value set in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']` is respected by phpMyAdmin and displayed in configuration screen. That suggests, that all is fine with paths and configuration file itself.

Is it possible, that after first manual change of this (or any other) configuration value (using UI) PMA is ignoring any changes to configuration file? Or what should I do to force phpMyAdmin to respect `LoginCookieValidity` set in my `config.inc.php`? Now, it seems to be ignoring this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you cleared the value in the Settings menu? If you have something set there and a different value in `config.inc.php`, the one from the Settings menu overrides the one in config.inc.php. So if your Settings menu still has the old value, whatever you do in config.inc.php won't take effect.

Failing that, it sounds like you did everything right -- I wonder if the php configuration file you've edited might be the wrong one? On some systems, there can be several copies of php.ini strewn about and some of them aren't even used at all. Try opening phpinfo (there's a link on the phpMyAdmin main page for "Show PHP information") and search that page for `gc_maxlifetime` to make sure the change actually worked in your PHP installation. Clearing the cache and logging out/back in again to phpMyAdmin are really the only steps to take with regards to the phpMyAdmin configuration. Hopefully checking the PHP configuration will clear this up for you.

Comment: No, I have that field in settings still filled out, because I didn't know, that it can overwrite `config.inc.php` settings. That's odd for me, I always thought (on other system), that this is exactly opposite, that config-file settings overwrites control panel ones, because they require higher level of privileges -- a FTP access, not just control panel access. Configuration files are OK (correct one), as I'm talking about localhost developer's environment (XAMPP) on Windows. Thank you for your effort and suggestions.